# Why Language service in Azure requires a location instead of an endpoint

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Most examples of `Cognitive Services` in `Azure` require an `endpoint` and a `key`. However the `Language` service in `Azure` needs a `Location`, instead of `Endpoint`? Why?
?
https://microsoftlearning.github.io/AI-900-AIFundamentals/instructions/04b-translate-text-and-speech.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the first part of the endpoints are the same, and the system use region to append to the general endpoint URL to generate the whole endpoint as below screenshot - **api.cognitiveservice.microsofttranslator.com/[region/location]**

I think this is just the difference of how to generate endpoint between different products - directly generate the whole endpoint URL or do A + region

Hope this helps.

[image]